# ASP.NET: Textbox lost Enabled value on postback

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, textbox, asp.net-4.0

I have a textbox, that programatically i set it 'Enabled = false'.  When the page, after this change, get a postback, this textbox return the enabled value to true.  why?

I have the textbox into a updatepanel.

Comment: Are you setting in code-behind in the Page_Load event?

Comment: Please add some code and markup.

Comment: As this is not the normal behavior, it's probably something in your code. And since you didn't provide any code - there is no way to help you...

Comment: I'm pretty sure what's happening is you're disabling the control via the UpdatePanel but when the post back occurs it's resetting everything - you would need to set Enabled to false even during the post back based on the conditions.

Comment: i´m setting this value on code-behind in a event for other control (a textchanged for other textbox explicit).

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting it in code-behind in the Page_Load event, you need to remember that Page_Load occurs even on postbacks.  You have two options.

Place it with in a block that checks to see if the page is a postback.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

or set it in `Page_Init` instead.

If you're not already familiar with it, be sure you understand the Page Lifecycle.  This is must-know information for ASP.NET developers.  Read about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i understand you, however, this textbox not ever be enabled=false, i switch this attribute when other textbox fire the event "textchanged", and if the textbox that fire the event, have a especific value, i changed this other textbox to disabled.
maybe i just evaluate the condition any way that i get a postback... but this condition have a lot of database querys that can slow the postback

Answer (score 0):

In the page_load, do the following:

```
If (IsPostBack) Then
    Textbox1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: but this textbox not ever be enabled=false, i switch this attribute when other textbox fire the event "textchanged", and if the textbox that fire the event, have a especific value, i changed this other textbox to disabled.